# How to get an updated field value from Excel in PHP

Tags: php, excel

I have developed a PHP application which can communicate with an Excel sheet. From Excel I am successfully retrieving a value from the shell, processing it in my application. However, I would like to get the new value from the Excel shell whenever it is updated, so that I can call the required PHP function to process this new value. How can I achieve this?

Note that I am using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for reading and writing, and that the Excel spreadsheet may be updated every 10-50 seconds.

Comment: You can create a PHP script which check if Excel file has changed and run this script via a cron task.

Comment: @Corum can you give me some detail information about it or any example code for statrup?

Comment: I can't give you PHP code, because I don't know the processing you want to do and your current architecture. But for CRON, it's simpler. To begin, have you ever used scheduled tasks (Windows / Microsoft server) or cron tab (Unix) ?